# Prove $\phi$ is a bijection

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f : \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function with continuous derivative ($f \in C^1(\mathbb R)$) Suppose furthermore that there is $k  \in \mathbb R$ with the property that $|f'(x)|  \leq  k$ for all $x  \in  \mathbb R$.

Show that there is a constant $c > 0$ such that the function $\phi(x) = x + cf(x)$ is a bijection.

Need help how to start.

Comment: yeah f'(x) instead of f(x). sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take $c \in (0, \frac{1}{k})$ and let $\phi (x) = x + cf(x)$. Notice that

$$\phi'(x) \geq 1 - ck > 0$$

Thist shows that $\phi$ is injective. (Why?)

In order to show that $\phi$ is surjective use the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) for $\phi$ with $x > 0$ and $y < 0$

- for [0,x] there exists $\xi \in (0,x)$ such that

$$\phi(x) - \phi (0) \geq \phi'(\xi)(1 - ck)x$$

then $\phi \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$

Similar approach to $y < 0$.

Then conclude by the [Intermediate Value There](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) that there exists $z \in (y,x)$ such that for any $d \in \mathbb R$

$$\phi (z) = d$$

Comment: +1 You should show that the derivative $f'(x)$ is bounded for the first line of the argument to work :-) which it is, of course

Comment: @Ant it is bounded by hypothesis.

Comment: To my understanding $f$ is bounded, $f'$ is not (a priori). Since it's continuos on $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is bounded then also $f'$ is bounded.. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Ant Oh, you're right!! I guess it's a typo then. Should I  just add to my answer? I had this question on my test! With the derivative bounded.

Comment: How is $f'$ bounded? How about if $f(x):=\sin x^2$? $f$ is $C^1$ and it is bounded but has unbounded derivative, no?

Comment: @Uzman The OP has fixed it. And I guess your example doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @Uzman Oh, I though it was $\sin^2 x$ instead of $\sin x^2$, my bad. Your example totally works.

Comment: No worries :). Let us also correct that the derivative of a bounded function need not be bounded.

Comment: @Uzman you're right, I totally got that wrong :)

Comment: thank you @AaronMaroja. i did not quite get the surjection part. I get we use the x an y interval

Comment: @Nawaf You're welcome!! Yes you get it, you take an $x$ sufficiently positive and $y$ sufficiently negative. Then $\phi (y) < d < \phi (x)$.

Comment: thank you @AaronMaroja.                                           but i did not quite get the last part of the surjection. we put two intervals then by IVT we found z such that ϕ(z)=d right?. how this proves surjectivity.

Comment: Well, you want prove that $\phi (\mathbb R) = \mathbb R$. One inclusion is obvious, now you need to show that $\mathbb R \subseteq \mathbb \phi(\mathbb R)$. Thus you take any $d \in \mathbb R$ and show that there exists $z \in \mathbb R$ such that $\phi (z) =d$. That's why.

Comment: @AaronMaroja it makes sense now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Nawaf Nice!! I'm glad I could help. If the answer was helpful, don't forget to accept it. Just hit the $\check$.